# How to run "sencha app watch" without a webserver

Tags: extjs, sencha-cmd

I am already serving my ExtJS 5.1 development application on a local (nginx) web server, and I don't need the development webserver from Sencha Cmd when running `sencha app watch`.

Is there any flag or other command equivalent but without running this extra web server?

Alternativelly, what would be an equivalent command for building the development app (not making the entire build proccess of a production app) but without the "**watch**" characteristics? ie. issued automatically by the IDE every time I save a `.js` file.

Comment: I am looking for the same answer.By now I am using the IDE integrated tomcat/jboss web server to publish the web app.And I need to refresh the browser every time after modifying the java script files.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can switch off the web server.

Go to the `sencha.cfg` file located at `<App name>\app\.sencha\app` and put at the bottom of the file:

`skip.web.start=true` or `skip.web.start=1`

Answer (score 0):

For later versions of ExtJS (not sure, I think 6.x or 7.x) you can run the command below to disable the web server:

```
$ sencha app watch -w=false
```

or

```
$ sencha app watch --web-server=false
```

Answer (score -1):

I am using Sencha Cmd 6.7.0.63

Create a **local.properties** file in the app directory and add there:

```
skip.web.start=true
```

Vales that can be set in the  **local.properties** file are to be looked up in the sencha installation dir:

```
Sencha\Cmd\6.7.0.63\ant\build\app\build.properties
Sencha\Cmd\6.7.0.63\ant\build\app\*.properties
```